# UITableViewCell option view overlap interactionable

Tags: ios, uitableview, overlay

I have a UI with tableview and button at the buttom like this.
[image]

when user click the three dotes, It will show an overlay/overlap view that show several button option to choose.

The button inside cell (Report) is tapable (clickable), but button outside the cell (Edit and Delete) cannot be clicked. Anyone can help? Thank you.

Here is the XIB.
[image]

Comment: how you are presenting the overlay button view ? please provide the code also to understand the problem

Comment: hi @vivekDas, I use xib to build the cell, is it enough?

Comment: Hey this will not work man, in the xib you can see the other two button's area is outside of the cell/superview so it will not take touches.

Comment: yes sir, do you have idea how to achive this?

Comment: You have to create another overlay view or custom popover view which will contain the three button UI, and on clicking the three dots you have to present that overlay or popover.

Comment: what do you mean by `create another overlay view`? The view is owned by the cell, right?

Comment: yes another overlay view, this view is owned by the cell but the button view size is bigger and getting out of the cell, so it will not work because bottom part doesn't come under its superview's bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I endup using `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` (to be exact, I use [Popover](https://github.com/corin8823/Popover) library) to solve this problem.